# How can I get an alert when a specifc drive is under a preset amount using InsightsMetrics on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I am trying to get and alert like this one but using InsightsMetrics instead of Pref:

```
let setgbvalue = 200;//Set the disk space you want to check for.  
Perf  
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h) 
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "Free Megabytes" 
| where InstanceName != "D:"   
| where InstanceName  != "_Total"  
| where InstanceName != "HarddiskVolume1"  
| extend FreeSpaceGB = CounterValue/1024  
| summarize FreeSpace = min(FreeSpaceGB) by Computer, InstanceName  
| where FreeSpace < setgbvalue
```

This is what I tried:

```
let _minValue = 100; // Set the minValue according to your needs
InsightsMetrics
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(1h) // choose time to observe 
| where Origin == "vm.azm.ms"
| where Namespace == "LogicalDisk" and Name == "FreeSpacePercentage"
| where Val <= _minValue
| extend t=parse_json(Tags)
| summarize avg(Val) by bin(TimeGenerated, 10m), Computer, tostring(t["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
| sort by avg_Val asc
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing here. @Lebogang Mocoakae

Comment: I am trying to get alerts when the C: drive is under 200GBs. I want to exclude the D: drive from the alert. I previously used the Log analytics agent for this and I had no issues. Now I am using the Monitor agent.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get an alert when a specific drive is under a preset amount using Insights Metrics on Azure:

*You can use the below query to achieve the requirement.*

```bash
let _minValue = 100; 
InsightsMetrics
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(1h)
| where Namespace == "LogicalDisk" and Name == "FreeSpacePercentage"
| where Val <= _minValue
| extend t = parse_json(Tags)
| summarize avg(Val) by bin(TimeGenerated, 10m), Computer, tostring(t["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
| sort by avg_Val asc
```

***Output:***

[image]